# how to maximize scrollbar in Kivy python?

Tags: python, user-interface, scrollview, kivy

I am using multiTab in kivy. How to enlarge the scrollbar so that scrollbar can be moved(up_down) by mouse. I am using BoxLayout and RecycleView. The code below was working with gridLayout, but not in BoxLayout:

```
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
```

Comment: You can't actually drag that scrollbar to scroll, you need a seperate slider to do that.

Comment: Then how to do that when I'm using RecycleView and BoxLayout? Can you give some example? Thank you.

Comment: I think I used this example https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/A-draggable-scrollbar-using-a-slider when I was making my own, try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Here is an example of how to extend ScrollView to also get a dragable slider.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Builder.load_string("""
<ScrollSlider>:
    ScrollView:
        id: scrlvw
        bar_width: 0
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            size_hint_y:None
            cols:1
            height: self.minimum_height
            scroll_y: slider.value
            on_touch_move: slider.value = self.scroll_y
    Slider:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: root.width*0.2
        id: slider
        min: 0
        max: 1
        orientation: 'vertical'
        value: scrlvw.scroll_y
        on_value: scrlvw.scroll_y = self.value

""")


class ScrollSlider(BoxLayout):

    def custom_add(self, widget):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(widget)

class MyApp(App):


    def build(self):
        scrollslider = ScrollSlider()
        for i in range(1, 100):
            scrollslider.custom_add(Label(text=str(i), height=100, size_hint_y=None))
        return scrollslider

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

You need to use the `custom_add` to add widgets in the `ScrollSlider` or add them to the `GridLayout` in kivy.

I took some inspiration from the link @Edvardas Dlugauskas provided.

The code you provided does not work with `BoxLayout` because `BoxLayout` just takes the size of its parent. To be able to scroll you need to add sth into `ScrollView` which is larger than the `ScrollView` itself.