# How to populate data in TextInput when the TextInput data are declared globally

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, textinput

I am unable to do some changes in the below code. 
(1) the value at every textinput (more clearly, the textinput value of column2 will differ from column3 textinput value, as per in picture that I have attached) will differ and those value should be stored globally(like what 'Row' variable is doing in this code)
(2) the label value should be like the image, but in this existing code, the label is getting the TextInput(or Row) value.
(3) the scrolling option should be increased(zooming) so that we can go up/down by pulling the scroll. 
I appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

ROWS = ['ac', 'asd', 'kjhgf', 'b', 'bn', 'sdf', 'ytrwd', 'hfs', 'erf',  'boo']
ROWS = ROWS * 10000

Builder.load_string("""
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#:import dp kivy.metrics.dp
<ScrollSlider>:
    ScrollView:
        id: scrlvw
        bar_width: 0
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            size_hint_y:None
            cols:1
            height: self.minimum_height
            scroll_y: slider.value
            on_touch_move: slider.value = self.scroll_y
    Slider:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: root.width*0.2
        id: slider
        min: 0
        max: 1
        orientation: 'vertical'
        value: scrlvw.scroll_y
        on_value: scrlvw.scroll_y = self.value

<Row>:
    spacing: 50
    text: txtinpt.text
    Label:
        text: root.text


    TextInput:
        id: txtinpt
        text: root.text

    TextInput:
        id: txtinpt
        text: root.text

    TextInput:
        id: txtinpt
        text: root.text

    Button:
        text: 'save'
        on_press:
            app.data[root.row_id]['text'] = root.text



<Test>:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab2'
        RecycleView:
            data: app.data
            viewclass: Factory.Row
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                padding: 50, 50, 50, 50
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, None
                size: self.minimum_size
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                default_size: 0, dp(36)



""")

class ScrollSlider(BoxLayout):

    def custom_add(self, widget):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(widget)

class Row(BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()
    row_id = NumericProperty()


class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    data = ListProperty()
    scrollslider = ScrollSlider()
    def build(self):
        self.data = [{'row_id': i, 'text': x} for i, x in enumerate(ROWS)]
        test = Test()
        return test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: kivy image]

Comment: Please reduce your example to one particular question. It is way easier to help you if you have one precise question.

Comment: regarding (3), you cannot grab the slider. You need to add a slider on your own. see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45397261/6646710

Comment: Ok, While there was only one TextInput, then storing value in the global variable "ROWS" worked. but now as per the diagram given above, multiple TextInputs are there, and the values will also be different in each textInput. How to do that?

Comment: you could use a global list